Improving speed and robustnes for opencv HoughCircles for only single circle
There are many threads on how to detect multiple circles via OpenCV's HoughCircles function, and I understand that this is a complex task with no single good answer. However, maybe someone can give some hints for parameters for the specific problem of only finding a single circle. I also want to only get an answer when the algorithm is sure enough, so no 'maybe', please. The data sometimes has a background of 100-150 (out of 255) with the signal peaking all the way to >200 for most of the time. Does the function handle offsets well or would it be worth to spend some time to remove the background?
My current code:
im8blur = cv2.blur(im8, (n, n))

or
im8blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im8, (n,n), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

with n in the range of 3-10 for the first case or >30 for the second case.
Then, with these parameters, the results are best, but it takes >20 minutes for 140 images...
detected_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(im8blur,  
                                    cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
                                    minDist = 2000,
                                    param1 = 14,
                                    param2 = 4,
                                    minRadius = 400,
                                    maxRadius = 600)

My circles are all around 520px in radius, but setting the minRadius to 500 or setting the maxRadius to -1 yielded worse results.
For my 1400x1400 pictures, I picked a 2000 minDist to ensure only one circle to be found.
However, I still get mixed results. Only when it is super clear, I get a good fit, but most of the time a circle is places somewhere.
For the case of only one circle, there must be a better solution...?

Images? We can't help you without seeing your data. If it is not possible to upload the exact file, an approximation might help

I would love to be able to just say "pics or ...." but the humor and levity in that is probably not universally understood

"Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is not in a reproducible format, nor have you provided an example image.
